# Excel multiple goal seek macro code error

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a simple macro found in internet for Multiple Goal Sheek in Excel 2010. The link is [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=433)

The point is that the macro is working in the example test `MultipleGoalSeek(KB19).xls`.
given in that link.

But when I try to apply it in my excel sheet, it only solves the first Goal Sheek problem, leaving the others un-calculated. I have no idea why although the macro seems pretty easy (maybe because they are not integers?)

I attach my [excel problem](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3giks8OOc1eSXZDRmNnOS1jWmM/edit?usp=sharing) with the macro.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm .... this is a very early piece of brettdj code, it dates back to my beginner days a decade or so ago. And it shows .... !

The issue is in the third last row of the code, contrary to the instructons in the file, it was designed to work over *columns* only (I was running a time-based inventory adjustment at the time)

Change

```
For i = 1 To TargetVal.Columns.Count
```

to

```
For i = 1 To TargetVal.Cells.Count
```

And it works fine on your sample

I will work on the orginal code to run with variant arrays.

Comment: Are you the owner of that macro? hahaha, I never expected this. Yes!! it works, thank you so much. Not only for helping now, buy because sharing your work. It will help me a lot!!

Comment: Yes, one and the same. This one I wrote out of necessity - now will need to go back and fix it up to a decent standard. :)